# am getting error on the 6th line of the following code in java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-poi, xwpf

```
JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
int returnvalue=chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
try
{
    if(returnvalue==chooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(newFileInputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile()));
}catch(Exception e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
```

error is

```
cannot find symbol constructor XWPFDocument(java.io.fileinputstream)
```

Can please anybody help me to solve the problem?

**EDIT :-**

Images are shown below--->

[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

Comment: i cant even read [follow this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Your problem is that you probably have to have the JAR or library that references said `XWPFDocument` Is it added to your project properly?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 `FileInputStream` extends from `InputStream`...

Comment: yes.added a lot of jar files.and i cn refer to XWPFDocument.but when i use constructor XWPFDocument(java.io.fileinputstream),am getting error

Comment: you have `newFileInputStream` and not `new fileInputStream`

Comment: also imported java.io.fileinputstream.but am getting error

Comment: sorry robert its my typing mistake here.but done it right in my program.

Comment: casing and spacing are important. `FileInputStream` is different than `fileInputStream` is different than `fileinputstream`

Comment: ya.again sorry.but right in my program.casing and spacing are right in my program.but i dont know why this error happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error came out to be what you mentioned in the comment and not in the question exactly.It is related to your import.

Try `import java.io.FileInputStream;` and `import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;`

**EDIT :-**

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile());
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(in);
```

Saving your application, and compiling it afresh would solve your purpose.

Next thing which I found is that you have given your class name as `read`.That's poor way of naming class! You shouldn't do that because that doesn't conform to the Java naming convention. Rename your class to something like `MyReadClass`.

Comment below as to what you got after performing these operations.If successful,please accept the answer...

Comment: it is my typing mistake here since am a new user for stack overflow.forgiv me for this time.but i had imported import java.io.FileInputStream; in my program

Comment: Can't believe this!!! But,you might be telling right @sreeram. Also,why don't you try with InputStream Class. `import java.io.InputStream;`

Comment: since am using netbeans,when i type the 6th line of code,it shows add import for  java.io.FileInputStream.if i change this,it will become an unused import and of no use.but my error still exists

Comment: I suggest you doing this---> convert FileInputStream into InputStream using `InputStream in=new FileInputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile());`
Also,break the sixth line into two steps as I mentioned in the above line.
Next,do,` XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(in);`

Comment: i also do the same code in netbeans 8,6.9,6.8.but i got the same error.iam very much confident that there is no error in the code since stack overflow suggests that this code is correct.thats why i choose this.then why i got the same error again.dnt knw y.cn anybody help me plz??

Comment: @sreeram-Have you imported the `org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument` for sure? Also,would you please share a snapshot of your code using this site or some other image hosting sites? I am really trying to help you however I can!

Comment: @  shekhar suman -ya i have impoted it.am sure.i have 2 screen shots of my simple program.just a few lines of code.if u dont mind can u send your gmail id for sending the screen shots?

Comment: You don't need to send me personally the screenshots.You just leave here a link on free image hosting---`tinypic.com`.Upload your screenshot on that website and leave a link over here.I'll edit the question and will try to answer your doubt!

Comment: @ shekhar suman-i think u had seen my code.cn u help me to solve the problem?

Comment: THANK YOU!cn u upload ur edit on tinypic and send me the link?

Comment: You must clean and build your project and restart your project.Then,tr executing it afresh and comment as to any further improvement took place! @sreeram